# R summarize data by presence of a current event

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I was searching on the web for a solution to a problem that seems easy but gives me headaches.

I have a dataframe with several columns.

```
Location<-c("East","East","East","West","West","West","North","North","North")
Year<-c(2009,2009,2010,2010,2011,2011,2012,2013,2013)
Product<-c("A","A","B","A","A","A","A","B","A")
User<-c("GH","GH","AB","AB","AAB","A","G","AB","AB")
a<-data.frame(Location,Year,User,Product)
```

And I need to summarize its columns. I prefer to do it with ddply and for column `User` this looks like:

```
ddply(a,.(Location),summarize,
      User=sum(User=="AB")/NROW(User)
            )
```

However, for the column `Product` I need to count  the presence of any "A" in every year as 1=present,0=absent (multiple occurences are not counted individually, e.g. for West in 2011 there was Product A used therefore =1). This should then be divided by the total number of unique years for the corresponding location.

The output should look like

```
 Location   User     Product
1     East 0.3333333    0.5
2    North 0.6666667    1
3     West 0.3333333    1
```

I hope I described my problem well enough and someone could give me a hint on how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is answer you were looking for:

```
ddply(a,.(Location),summarise,
      User=sum(User=="AB")/NROW(User),
      Product =length(unique(Year[Product=="A"]))/length(unique(Year)))

  Location      User Product
1     East 0.3333333     0.5
2    North 0.6666667     1.0
3     West 0.3333333     1.0
```

Comment: It's better to use `summarise` instead of `summarize`, else you could get the error: `Error in is.list(by) : 'by' is missing`

Comment: @Pigeon, `summarise` is a `plyr` function, `summarize` is a base function

Comment: very nice. Thank you!